# ClassNotFoundException - RMI

Tags: java, rmi

Please see the code below:

```
package RMITest;

    import java.rmi.Naming; 
    import java.rmi.RemoteException; 
    import java.rmi.server.UnicastRemoteObject; 
    public class HelloImpl extends UnicastRemoteObject implements Hello 
    { 

    public HelloImpl() throws RemoteException {} 

    public String sayHello() { return "Hello world!"; } 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        try 
        { 
            System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","172.16.4.142");
            HelloImpl obj = new HelloImpl(); 
            // Bind this object instance to the name "HelloServer" 
            Naming.rebind("HelloServer", obj); 
        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        { 
            System.out.println("HelloImpl err: " + e.getMessage()); 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

I am trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~cappello/lectures/rmi/helloworld.shtml#5912.  The error I am getting is: ClassNotFoundException RMITest.Hello.  Hello is the interface.  Does the classpath need to point to the .class files or the .jar.  There do not appear to be any .jar files generated by Netbeans.

I am a .NET Developer so I am quite new to this.

Comment: Could you provide us with the stacktrace?

Comment: Sorry, but i do not see any correlation between tutorial and code

Comment: @Sanjeev, sorry.  I have updated the question.

Comment: Why are you setting `System.setProperty("java.rmi.server.hostname","172.16.4.142");` ?

Comment: @Daniel Figueroa, I have updated the question.

Comment: I don't see any package defined in your code above. It should perhaps be RMITest, based on your error.

Comment: @ManoDestra, I have edited the question.  I missed the first line.

Comment: I assume all you have in your Hello interface is the sayHello() method signature?

Comment: @ManoDestra The *content* of the interface class that wasn't found is irrelevant at this stage.

Comment: @Sanjeev For the same reason anyone would set it. If you don't know what it is, look it up. It doesn't have anything to do with this question.

Comment: @EJP I agree, however I like to get a grasp of the bigger picture too in order to get a better understanding of the OP's requirements.

Comment: @EJP earlier it was around connect exception (later it got updated to CNF), i wanted to check whether OP really know what he is trying with that statement and ip address in that